# Call a function with dynamic list of vars PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, function-calls

Let say i have function:

```
<?php
function myFunction($param1, $param2, /*0 or more extra args*/) {
  // do something with $param1 & $param2
  $args = func_get_args();
  $other_args = array_slice($args, 2); // get the dynamic args
  // do something with $other_args
}
?>
```

this enables to call:

```
<?php
myFunction($param1, $param2); // or
myFunction($param1, $param2, $param3); // or
myFunction($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4);
?>
```

But i want to know if it possible to to take an array of args and pass them into the function e.g:

```
<?php
$extra_args = array($param3, $param4); // this could also be
$extra_args = array($param3, $param4, $param5); // or any length array
?>
```

i would like to pass them as separate params into my function e.g

```
<?php
myFunction($param1, $param2 /* other args split up */);
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? You want to call your function with a array of params?

Comment: yea, that's what i want to do

Comment: This question seems very basic. Yes, you can pass a param of an array to the function as long as you build the function to handle it.

Comment: @Jeremy - he doesn't want to pass an array, he wants to use an array and have it passed as though each element in the array was passed as its own function parameter, like JavaScript's `function.prototype.apply()` method (if that helps).

Comment: Why does it have to be called as if all the args were passed as opposed to putting them in an array and handling them that way? I dont see why thats necessary. I do agree that your solution does match what the person is asking though @Utkanos

Comment: @sbditto85 - there are common cases for doing this in JavaScript. In PHP (not my main language) I can think of far fewer. Mostly useful for functions that expect a dynamic number of arguments rather than a set number, I expect.

Comment: @Utkanos - I would be interested in a few of those examples in JS (not my main language), i've personally never needed to do it in php (is my main language) but dont doubt there is a time when it might be needed.

Comment: @sbditto85 - if you drop me an e-mail through my website (see profile) I'll reply with some JS examples if interested. (Rather than list them here, where they're O/T to the question).

Comment: I have just [written a blog post on apply()](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Jul/The-magic-JavaScripts-apply-214), covering its magic and main uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeap - `call_user_func_array()`'.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Takes two arguments - the function name (as a string - or possibly, in PHP >= 5.3, an anonymous function, not sure) and an array of params.

Or for methods, `forward_static_call_array()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call-array.php

PHP's answer to JS's `function.prototype.apply()` :)

Comment: call_user_func_array will probably work for my scenario - can't believe I didn't think of that :) Also didn't know of forward_static_call_array - but unfortunately the function is static - good to know though.

Answer (score 1):

```
call_user_func_array('myFunction', 
    array_merge(
       array($param1,$param2),
       $extra_args));
```